# Evaluation of a Fourier transform integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis

I am interested in evaluating a Fourier transform integral
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \sin(kx) dx
$$
where
$$
f(x) = \frac{\exp(-a x^2) x}{x^2 + b^2}
$$
with $a, b, k > 0$. In Erdelyi's Tables of Integral Transforms, Vol. 1, pp. 74, equation (26), this integral evaluates to the following:
$$
\frac{\pi}{4} \exp(a^2 b^2) [\exp(-bk) \, \text{erfc}(ab - \frac{k}{2a}) - \exp(bk) \, \text{erfc}(ab + \frac{k}{2a})]
$$
But I cannot reproduce this result using contour integration. Can this integral be evaluated using contour integration? If not, is there a way to evaluate it directly?

Comment: I'd figure you can use the Residue Theorem, after some tedious calculation.

Comment: I don't know about a contour integration approach, but a few approaches can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4558529/16033).

Comment: @SeanRoberson I have tried Residue Theorem, but got an answer proportional to exp(-bk) instead of this one.

Comment: @RandomVariable Thank you very much for pointing to the existing solutions!